# How do I tell on GIT whether a reference is a branch or a tag?

Tags: git

How do I tell, given an arbitrary reference, whether it is a branch, a tag or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you fully expand the ref:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name v1.9-rc2
```

...where `v1.9-rc2` is the ref I care about.  That gives me the full reframe `refs/tags/v1.9-rc2`.  Tags start with `refs/tags`, branches start with `refs/heads`.